# Change child widget of parent | Flutter

Tags: flutter, callback, state

I'm coming to the point when state management have to be handled in my applications, even if I just started to learn more about it when I red through the question being similar to my title.

I want to learn state management and the including things by having a clean solution for my following code:

This is my Parent Widget. However I wan't to pass data coming from the SideMenu in order to manage the **WidgetDependingOnSideMenu** Widget. To be clear: When I press on a SideMenuItem at my SideMenu class, the child (of the second Expanded in my MainScreen) should change to another one given by the SideMenuItem (onClick function).

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // final GlobalKey<SideMenuState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Responsive(
        desktop: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(flex: _size.width > 1340 ? 2 : 4, child: SideMenu()),
            Expanded(
                flex: _size.width > 1340 ? 3 : 5, child: WidgetDependingOnSideMenu()),
            Expanded(flex: _size.width > 1340 ? 8 : 10, child: Container()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my SideMenuItem. The function **toggleActiveState** is called when I click on the SideMenuItem. As already explained, at this point the parent should receive the information that it have to change some child in his class.

```
            SideMenuItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.inbox,
                  size: 20,
                  color: isActiveList[0] ? kPrimaryColor : kGrayColor,
                ),
                activeState: isActive,
                textColor: isActiveList[0] ? kTextColor : kGrayColor,
                title: "Bestellungen",
                toggleActiveState: (activeState) {
                  clearIsActiveList();
                  setState(() {
                    isActiveList[0] = !activeState;
                  });
                }),
```

Well, I hope I can turn into that topic by having a clean solution. If you need any more information tell me. Just enough for today, have a nice evening.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem with the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1qu8X7f36k

First of all I made use of the Provider Package:
https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Then I created following class with a ChangeNotifier in my SideMenu:

```
class ActiveWidgetNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  Widget activeWidget = Bestellungen();
  void changeActiveWidget(Widget newWidget) {
    activeWidget = newWidget;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

onPressed at the Button:

```
Provider.of<ActiveWidgetNotifier>(context, listen: false)
                      .changeActiveWidget(NewWidgetThatShouldBeDisplayed());
```

Then I added following code at my parent in order to display the changed child:

```
            Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Provider.of<ActiveWidgetNotifier>(context).activeWidget),
```

Finally added a ChangeNotifierProvider at my main.dart:

```
void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ActiveWidgetNotifier(), child: App()));
}
```

And all you have to is restarting you application in order to keep errors away. That's worked for me.